# Nginx failed space when upload

Tags: nginx, upload, device, failed

I've a problem with my nginx server. He is a storage server, and when i want to upload a file (2,5G) i can show any error on my error.log

`2016/02/08 03:26:24 [crit] 7843#0: *1154 pwrite() "/var/lib/nginx/body/0000000388" failed (28: No space left on device), client: 78.229.62.244, server: www1.mywebsite.net, request: "POST /upload/ HTTP/1.1", host: "www1.mywebsite.net", referrer: "http://www.mywebsite.net/"
2016/02/08 03:28:37 [crit] 7843#0: *1476 pwrite() "/var/lib/nginx/body/0000000526" failed (28: No space left on device), client: 78.229.62.244, server: www1.mywebsite.net, request: "POST /upload/ HTTP/1.1", host: "www1.mywebsite.net", referrer: "http://www.mywebsite.net/"
2016/02/08 03:29:45 [crit] 7844#0: *1518 pwrite() "/var/lib/nginx/body/0000000550" failed (28: No space left on device), client: 78.229.62.244, server: www1.mywebsite.net, request: "POST /upload/ HTTP/1.1", host: "www1.mywebsite.net", referrer: "http://www.mywebsite.net/"
2016/02/08 03:32:50 [crit] 7846#0: *1572 pwrite() "/var/lib/nginx/body/0000000588" failed (28: No space left on device), client: 78.229.62.244, server: www1.mywebsite.net, request: "POST /upload/ HTTP/1.1", host: "www1.mywebsite.net", referrer: "http://www.mywebsite.net/"
2016/02/08 03:33:23 [crit] 7846#0: *1579 pwrite() "/var/lib/nginx/body/0000000592" failed (28: No space left on device), client: 78.229.62.244, server: www1.mywebsite.net, request: "POST /upload/ HTTP/1.1", host: "www1.mywebsite.net", referrer: "http://www.mywebsite.net/"`

And here is my df -h : 
`root@www1:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md2         96G   20G   72G  22% /
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs           6.3G   33M  6.3G   1% /run
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md3        1.7T  285G  1.4T  18% /home`

My site config :

`upstream mywebsite {
    server localhost:8000;
}`

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mywebsite.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/mywebsite.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mywebsite.error.log;
    client_max_body_size 10240M;

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_pass_header Server;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
proxy_read_timeout 1200;
}
```

}

Nginx conf :

root@www1:/etc/nginx# cat nginx.conf 
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
}
http {

```
##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# SSL Settings
##

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

}

A little df -i :

Sorry, here is my df -i.

`root@sd-87855:/etc/nginx# df -i
Filesystem        Inodes  IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda3       61038592  51533  60987059    1% /
udev             8250054    355   8249699    1% /dev
tmpfs            8260392    457   8259935    1% /run
tmpfs            8260392      1   8260391    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            8260392      3   8260389    1% /run/lock
tmpfs            8260392     13   8260379    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2          48960    328     48632    1% /boot
/dev/sda5      594759680 115967 594643713    1% /home`

Thanks for your help, have a good day ;-)

Comment: What did you do yourself to solve the problem? Besides this: Please provide the output of `df -i`.

Comment: df -i return me that :
`Filesystem        Inodes  IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on 
/dev/sda3       61038592  51533  60987059    1% / 
udev             8250054    355   8249699    1% /dev 
tmpfs            8260392    457   8259935    1% /run 
tmpfs            8260392      1   8260391    1% /dev/shm 
tmpfs            8260392      3   8260389    1% /run/lock 
tmpfs            8260392     13   8260379    1% /sys/fs/cgroup 
/dev/sda2          48960    328     48632    1% /boot 
/dev/sda5      594759680 115967 594643713    1% /home`

Comment: Could you please put this into your question? It's quite hard to read like this.

Comment: done, sorry i'm stupid haha ;)

Comment: Could you please put it into your _question_ and delete your _answer_, which actually isn't one?

Comment: I've add the df -i on my question ;-)

Answer (score 2):

For me this issue is solved by pointing the temp body store to a file location with enough space.

```
client_body_temp_path /spool/nginx/client_temp 1 2;
```

See more about [client_body_temp_path](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_body_temp_path)  in documentation.